# Xamarin App won't run without google play services

Tags: c#, android, .net, google-maps, xamarin

I am new to Xamarin Android. I am trying to display a basic google map on my application. I have the API key etc set for google maps api. However when I run the emulator gives a message "App won't run without google play services".

I have installed all the packages/ SDKs using android sdk manager, I am trying using API level 22 (Android 5.0 Lollipop).

Below code is for initializing google maps (its downloaded from xamarin examples).

Can anyone please tell me what I am missing here.

```
      using System;
      using Android.App;
      using Android.Content;
      using Android.Gms.Maps;
      using Android.Gms.Maps.Model;
      using Android.Runtime;
      using Android.Views;
      using Android.Widget;
      using Android.OS;

      namespace App2
      {
       [Activity(Label = "App2", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
      public class MainActivity : Activity, IOnMapReadyCallback
      {
        private GoogleMap _gMap;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        GetMap();
    }

    private void GetMap()
    {

        if (_gMap == null)
        {
            FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<MapFragment>(Resource.Id.map).GetMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap map)
    {
        _gMap = map;
    }
  }
}
```

**Main.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

**Android Mainfest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    package="App2.App2" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
<application android:label="App2" android:icon="@drawable/Icon">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyCKBrF-_IrAQlkUyFG7GT4qgEJ7qOgyNRI" />
</application>
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
<!-- We need to be able to download map tiles and access Google Play Services-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- Allow the application to access Google web-based services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!-- Google Maps for Android v2 will cache map tiles on external storage -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!-- Google Maps for Android v2 needs this permission so that it may check the connection state as it must download data -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<!-- These are optional, but recommended. They will allow Maps to use the My Location provider. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

[image: Error]
[image: All SDKs Installed]

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be, that the device, or in this case the emulator, does not have Google Play Services installed. The package that is within the Android app just provide access to Google Play Services, which is generally installed on the device itself. In this sense, Google Play Services is more like a shared runtime.

To fix this, you should be able to install Google Play Services on the emulator by following this [guide](https://university.xamarin.com/resources/how-to-install-google-play-on-android-emulator).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi clb, thanks for replying. I followed your instructions and downloaded the appropriate zip files, but the problem is that I cannot drag drop it on my player, it gives me circle (ban) icon when I try to drop the zip on player. Any idea what might be causing this.

Comment: Hey! I will need to see if I can reproduce that on my system. I will reply back on this thread once I have done so

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to run the app on an emulator image that does not have Google Play Services installed.

First and foremost I would always recommend using a physical device for testing, but if you need to test various API levels for which you don't own a device then using an emulator would suffice.

If you're using the Google AVD then you can [create a new virtual device](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html) that already contains Google Play Services.

If you're using the Xamarin Android Player then you can use [this guide](https://university.xamarin.com/resources/how-to-install-google-play-on-android-emulator) that @clb mentioned.  However, please bear in mind that Xamarin Android Player is Preview software and not officially supported.  If this is the emulator you're having problems installing the Google Play Services with then your best option for support would be to [file a bug report](https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1730025-where-to-report-issues-with-the-android-player-preview). (The guide currently shows the wrong location for the logs, which are now obtained by (Windows) right-clicking the bottom bar (Mac) clicking the Help menu > Generate Bug Report - logs will be zipped on your desktop)

If you're still having problems then please let me know what emulator you're using and I'll see if I can help further!

Comment: Hi Alan, I checked my app on a physical device & it works fine. I guess for now I will have to live with it till Xamarin Player releases a new version. Another possibility may be that I am running windows 10 Home which does not have hyper-v.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the problem appears to be that you don't have Google Play Services (aka Google APIs) installed on the emulator. Here's a link to a tutorial I wrote showing you how to do that. There's a video too: [https://birdsbits.wordpress.com/2016/05/26/testing-location-aware-apps-on-an-emulator](https://birdsbits.wordpress.com/2016/05/26/testing-location-aware-apps-on-an-emulator/)

Comment: It would be helpful if you post some information right here, in addition to providing the link to your blog.  Links can rot.

Comment: The key is installing the Google APIs via the SDK manager, and then selecting that when setting up your device -- specifically in the CPU/ABI section.