# wont run without Google Play services

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

The code builds and runs but I am getting Google Play services issues as follows. I do not know what I am missing. I am using Xamarin Android Player (XAP) emulator.

In the Reference

[image]

[image]

Comment: the device you are using needs to have google play services. Chances are the emulator does not support google play services

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin App won't run without google play services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36380010/xamarin-app-wont-run-without-google-play-services)

Comment: Xamarin Android Player (XAP) is deprecated and did not include Google Store/Play/etc... in the default images as only officially licensed emulator images are allowed to include Google apps (GApps). There are downloads available to install GApps on such images after the fact, but you are much better off using the official Google Android x86 AVD with Intel HAXM and images that include the official GApps... https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/accelerating_android_emulators/

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin Android Player was deprecated some time ago, so we would not advise using it anymore as it will no longer be updated.

Having said that, we do have some old instructions here which may assist with this question: https://university.xamarin.com/resources/how-to-install-google-play-on-android-emulator

One of the motivations of XAP was to make it easy to have a well-performing emulator. Moving forward, we suggest using AVDs from Google which are now just as fast thanks to HAXM: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/accelerating_android_emulators/

Comment: The x86/x64 images have been there for a long time, along with HAXM. It is not something that just happened recently. Devs just haven't been informed about it. I think the first images appeared around 2014.